# 16.04 LTS and /dev/shm/ Files Disappearing

Tags: 12.04, 16.04, shm

I am migrating a web application that was previously running on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. It makes extensive use of `/dev/shm/`. I'm finding that the application data is disappearing from `/dev/shm/` on the Ubuntu 16.04 LTS server.

Is there some sort of garbage collection that's deleting the files and directories from there? I see that 12.04 is configured with this symbolic link: `/dev/shm -> /run/shm`, whereas 16.04 has exactly the opposite: `/run/shm -> /dev/shm`. I don't see how that would make any difference, though.

---

**UPDATES**

- I suspected AppArmor, but removing it did not change the behavior
- The removal of the directory structures seems to happen every five minutes
- Directories with files in them eventually get deleted, but not as quickly
- I'm suspecting the age of the files/directories affects deletion
- It looks like [this guy is experiencing the same issue](https://superuser.com/questions/1117764/why-are-the-contents-of-dev-shm-is-being-removed-automatically).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After hours of searching and reading, I found the culprit. It's a setting for [`systemd`](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/). The `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` contains default configuration options, with each of them commented out. The `RemoveIPC` option is set to `yes` by default. That option tells `systemd` to clean up interprocess communication (IPC) for "user accounts" who aren't logged in. This does not affect "system accounts"

In my case, the files and directories were being created for a user account, not a system account.

There are two possible solutions:

1. Create the files with/for a system user -- a user created with the system option (`adduser -r` or `adduser --system`)
2. Edit `/etc/systemd/logind.conf`, uncomment the line `RemoveIPC=yes`, change it to `RemoveIPC=no`, save, and reboot the system

In my case, I went with option #2 because the user was already created.

**References:**

- [RemoveIPC prematurely removes IPC segments](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/4532)
- [Change default value of RemoveIPC in logind.conf](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/2039)
- PostgreSQL: [Systemd](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Systemd)
- Oracle: [3.5 Database Installation and Operation Fails if RemoveIPC=yes Is Configured for systemd](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E52668_01/E67200/html/section-t51_kcn_f5.html)

Comment: Insanity, why is this the default behaviour? :|

Comment: @ffledgling - I can't quite figure it out

Comment: when restart system is not an option, simply restart logind: sudo systemctl restart systemd-logind.service